# How can I programmatically change a system message?

Tags: 8, status-messages

I want to change or hide a message shown from the `CommentForm` class.

In my `entity_insert()` hook I either unset `$_SESSION['messages']` and add a new message or call `drupal_get_message($type, TRUE)`.

The problem is that the new message will be set before the one I want to change; if I unset the message array, the new message will be gone too.

I also tried to hook in the specific form and add a submission handler, but that doesn't work.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]  = 'my_module_comment_form_submit';
}

/**
 * Submit handler.
 */
function my_module_comment_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $message = $_SESSION['messages'];
}
```

How can I programmatically change a system message?

Comment: Did you try unsetting only $_SESSION['messages']['status'] also?

Comment: Yes my problem was that in my hook the fully message does not exist yet so I have to get it at a later point to check on it an manipulate it.

Comment: so maybe set in using different type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System messages are stored in a [Symfony Flashbag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Session%21Flash%21FlashBag.php/class/FlashBag/8.7.x), so there is no need to hack session variables, which can change from version to version. In Drupal 8.5 a new Messenger service was introduced to encapsulate the symfony flash bag and you can delete messages with [deleteAll()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Messenger%21MessengerInterface.php/function/MessengerInterface%3A%3AdeleteAll/8.5.x):

```
\Drupal::messenger()->deleteAll();
```

Comment: Ah you mean first delete with the mentioned method and then add your own with `\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage()`?

Comment: This is great for adding a new message, but deleteAll() will not remove generic node create messages if placed in hook_entity_insert.

Comment: @jhchnc Trying to do this in Drupal 9.3.13, and has found the same thing as jhchnc. This does not  remove generic node create messages if placed in hook_entity_insert.

Comment: @FreeRadical,  my answer was responding to the general topic in the title and the attempts to hack session variables. The timing is a different issue. You can't delete messages which will be set in the future. See [this great answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/293137/47547) how to add a submit handler after ::save setting the message.

Comment: do a `drupal_register_shutdown_function` in `hook_entity_insert` and nuke from the shutdown function...

Answer (score 14):

I was seeking a similar solution. I found [How can I remove a message shown from a different module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788080/how-can-i-remove-a-message-shown-from-a-different-module) which show how to achieve it using `hook_preprocess_status_messages()`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 *
 * @param $variables
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_status_messages(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['message_list']['status'])){
    $status_messages = $variables['message_list']['status'];
    foreach($status_messages as $delta => $message) {
      if (strpos((string) $message, 'The message that I am expecting') !== FALSE) {
        $variables['message_list']['status'][$delta] = "Some different message text";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped in my case since I wanted to alter the message and not create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer might be not to use hook_entity_insert(). By that time, it is too late: the content has already been created, so the system will create the message accordingly.

As the [hook_entity_insert documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.2.x) says: hook_entity_insert responds to the creation of a new entity.

Maybe try [another hook from the Entity API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/8.2.x), one that does not cause the unwanted message to be generated.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 delete message:

```
/**
 * Deletes status message after user registration.
 */
function YOURMODULE_user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
  $messenger->deleteByType('status');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'forms_opm_user_register_form_submit';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! You may also want to look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/311262/12076

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming the messages in question are `form_error`s from validation of the form:*

Rather than altering the messages after the fact you could override/replace the `#validate` function(s) that produce the errors in the first place (from hook_form_alter) and provide your own custom errors.

Comment: I tried that too unfortunately this message still shows up :-/

Comment: The message is a status message not an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function comment_limit_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (in_array('node-max', $_SESSION['messages']['status']) && in_array('user-max', $_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
    drupal_get_messages('status', TRUE);
    drupal_set_message(t('The comment limit for this node has been reached!'));
    drupal_set_message(t('Your comment limit has been reached!'));
  }
  elseif (in_array('node-max', $_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
    drupal_get_messages('status', TRUE);
    drupal_set_message(t('The comment limit for this node has been reached!'));
  }
  elseif (in_array('user-max', $_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
    drupal_get_messages('status', TRUE);
    drupal_set_message(t('Your comment limit has been reached!'));
  }
}
```

This looks a little prettier and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `unset($SESSION['_symfony_flashes']['status'][0])`. In my case, `unset($_SESSION['messages']['status'])` didn't work. Then I was able to do `\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('My message here'))`.

Hope this helps someone.