# What is correct way to override the field required error messages on custom form?

Tags: 8, forms

I have installed clientside validation contributed module in my Drupal 8 Project. Now all client side validations are looking uniformed throughout the site.

The only issue I am facing right now is about overriding Default error messages.

I have googled about how to override but everywhere I am getting suggestion of removing `#required = true` from the field definition and then in form_validate I can set error message with the help of form_error_message like below:

```
$name = $form_state->getValue('name');
if (empty($name)) {
   $form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Email is required.'));
}
```

But is there any way to just override error message without removing required true & writing obvious logic once again like `if ( empty(field) )` then set custom error message.

Please provide if any other way than above

Comment: `Please provide if any other way than above` JS :p

Comment: My site is multi-lingual, how to manage that if I use JS? @NoSssweat

Comment: try [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/252421/27710)